# Is it possible to write stdout using write_csv() from readr?

Tags: r, bash, readr

I'm using `bash` to pipe data through an `Rscript` like so:

`cat random.csv | Rscript test.R arg >| delete.csv`

My aim is to use the `R` package `readr` to both read stdin and write stdout. I found the [answer to stdin here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/manipulatr/tSVUCm8kd1k/Rc_tytKv32oJ).

**test.R**

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
suppressMessages(library(readr))

args  <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

df.in <- read_csv(file("stdin"))

write_csv(df.in, path = stdout())
```

The above code produces the following error message at the command line:

**Error Message**

```
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
Calls: write_csv -> write_delim -> normalizePath -> path.expand
Execution halted
```

I have also tried `write_csv(df.in, file("stdout"))` and `write_csv(df.in, stdout())` producing the same error message.

For reproducibility, here's a link to a `random.csv`

[Definition of variables, by WHO for the Global Tuberculosis Report [43kb]](https://extranet.who.int/tme/generateCSV.asp?ds=dictionary)

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/703

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a `format_csv` function for that in `readr`. Use this instead of `write_csv`:

```
cat(format_csv(df.in))
```

Comment: Thanks @m0nhawk - this is very close. The error message no longer appears. However, the `delete.csv` has all data printed on a single row when there should be multiple rows. If you wrap your answer with `cat()` the result is right on the money. e.g. `cat(format_csv(df.in))`. Update and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

for reading from stdin:

```
df.in <- read_csv(paste(collapse = "\n", readLines(file("stdin"))))
```

for writing to stdout:

```
writeLines(format_csv(tibble(a=c(1,2))), stdout())

#or
writeLines(format_csv(df.in), stdout())
```

Kudos to: [jimhester](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/703)

Answer (score 0):

With `write.table` and `write.csv` from base R, you can specify the filename as `""` to print to STDOUT:

```
file: either a character string naming a file or a connection open
      for writing.  ‘""’ indicates output to the console.
```

Example:

```
$ Rscript -e 'write.csv(head(mtcars),"",quote=F)'
,mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb
Mazda RX4,21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
Mazda RX4 Wag,21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
Datsun 710,22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
Hornet 4 Drive,21.4,6,258,110,3.08,3.215,19.44,1,0,3,1
Hornet Sportabout,18.7,8,360,175,3.15,3.44,17.02,0,0,3,2
Valiant,18.1,6,225,105,2.76,3.46,20.22,1,0,3,1
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `write.table`:

```
write.table(x, file = "foo.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
        qmethod = "double")
```

See the help page: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html

Comment: This answers the wrong question - OP knew how to format as CSV, but not how to write to `stdout`.